# In new window jquery functions not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom, codeigniter-3

I have this codes in my projects to open a new window to show and then, write the contents from my first window.After that i replace a certain div with some page,But in this window javascript funtions does not work.How to enable javascript function in newl generated widow?
   Here is my window generating jquery script

```
$('.ledger_edit').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var mywindow = window.open(window.location.href);
        $(mywindow.document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),

                success: function (data)
                {

                    $(mywindow.document).contents().find("div.content").html(data);
                    mywindow.onload = function () {
                        alert()

                        mywindow.contents().find(".ledger").select2();
                        calculateTotal();

                    }

                }
            });

        });

    })
```

my new window content div replaced with the below html code

```
    <form method="post" action="#">
                <input type="hidden" id="PID" name="PID" value="">
          <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action" value="update_project">
 ...
        <input type="button" id="proj_submit" class="ui blue submit button right floated" value="Update">
            </form></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $( "form" ).on( "submit", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    data = $(this).serialize();
     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "functions_new.php",
        data:data,
        success: function() {
            alert("Updated");
        }
});
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$new_date =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Hopefully this will work.

Comment: what did you get in this? $date = ($date - 25569) * 86400;

Comment: This is input date 02/06/2016,then i got after this equation float(-2209161600),

Comment: date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)) results answer 2016-10-22

Comment: you can skip this step $date = ($date - 25569) * 86400;

Comment: Then i got the result 1970-01-01

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `strtotime()` function,

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

Comment: what value $date return you?

Comment: This is input date 02/06/2016,then i got after this equation float(-2209161600),

Comment: date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date)) results answer 2016-10-22

Comment: my input date is 02-06-2016, but i got the result 2016-10-22